Combining Rows in Power BI/Power Query
Let's say I coach a track team, and I keep a log of my students' 800m times over time in PowerBI. My 800m dash table looks something like



Student
Date
800m




Rhyne
6/24/24
2:15


Rhyne
6/26/24
2:10


Rhyne
6/28/24
2:12


Alisha
6/24/24
2:09


Alisha
6/26/24
2:05


Alisha
6/28/24
2:03



I would like to have a separate table that is the average for the week:



Student
Average Time




Rhyne
2:12


Alisha
2:06



How can I accomplish this in PowerBI? The biggest issue I see is that I am effectively destroying or combining multiple rows into a single one, which is something I have not encountered before.
I have a separate table of general student details:



Student
Student ID
Class




Rhyne
38356929
Junior


Alisha
96821695
Senior



I was hoping that I could use Power Query to Add Column to this table, and have the value in each row be my students' average time that week. However, I could only access the data in this particular table to Add Column, and not any other table. What else could I do?

can you write some sql?'

@DanielA.White I'm not well versed in SQL, but I understand the basics.

I mean in this context? https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=afef78d0-80d7-469c-a180-bd7c4bb3185d

@DanielA.White I understand what that code is doing, but I'm not sure how I could apply it to my context as I work with multiple tables in Power Query.

You can make the summarization table like this:
Right click the query you want to summarize and select "Reference". A new query pops up that builds on it.
Now select the column you want to group by, in your case "Student", right click and select "Group by". Give the summarization column a name, select as operation "average" and as column the times, in your case "800m".
Then, you can merge it with your existing student table and expand only the average column.

This powerquery code  pasted into home..advanced editor...
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Seconds", each #duration(0,0,0,Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From(Text.Split([800m],":"){0})*60+Number.From(Text.Split([800m],":"){1}),1))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "WeekStarting", each Date.StartOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday),type date),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Student", "WeekStarting"}, {{"Average", each List.Average([Seconds]), type duration}})
in #"Grouped Rows"

takes the data from Table1, and calculates the average result of the 800m for each week for each person. You could then merge it into a different table showing student profiles rather simply with the home .. merge queries...


Load both the tables in the transform layer with the same column name.
Just have modifications on 800m dash table and then merge the student details with it.
Below is the code:
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCsqozEtV0lEy0zcyASIgy8jK0FQpVgdFygwuZYAuZQGXMgJLOeZkFmckoploYIkhBzfSwBRDDm6mgbFSbCwA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Student = _t, Date = _t, #"800m" = _t]),
#"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"800m", each "0:" & _, type text}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Prefix",{{"800m", type duration}, {"Date", type date}}),
#"Calculated End of Week" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Date", Date.EndOfWeek, type date}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Calculated End of Week",{{"Date", "End of Week"}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Student", "End of Week"}, {{"Week Average for 800m", each List.Average([800m]), type nullable duration}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"Student"}, Student, {"Student"}, "Student.1", JoinKind.RightOuter),
#"Expanded Student.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Student.1", {"Student ID", "Class"}, {"Student ID", "Class"})
in
#"Expanded Student.1"

